# get average of count by date in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Looking for an excel formula to help with how to get average of calls per day, week, month.

- 7/16/17 - 10 records
- 7/15/17 - 11 records
- 7/14/17 - 7 records
- 7/13/17 - 6 records

Average per day: 8.5

Source data:
[image: example link]

Comment: `AVERAGEIF` might be a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

```
=COUNTA(OFFSET(A2,0,0,COUNTA(A:A)-1))/SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(OFFSET(A2,0,0,COUNTA(A:A)-1),OFFSET(A2,0,0,COUNTA(A:A)-1)))
```

Comment: please explain. what is A2, what does it do? is it flexible?

Comment: A2 is the beginning of your data (according to the screenshot). The formulas takes the total dates found divided by the number of different dates to get an average.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. I was confused because the question didn't obviously contain a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

```
=AVERAGE(IF(FREQUENCY(A:A,A:A),FREQUENCY(A:A,A:A)))
```

`FREQUENCY(A:A,A:A)` is an array of frequencies; the frequency of each item at its first occurrence (zero in duplicate entries). We average these frequencies by eliminating the zero entries from the calculation.